# How can I set boilerplate information for the files generated by catalyst.pl?

Tags: perl, catalyst

When I use catalyst.pl to auto-generate my application, the AUTHOR section of the POD includes only my name like this.

```
 Kiffin Gish,,,
```

What are the missing fields and how can I use them? Is it possible to use another boilerplate for the PODs?

Answer (score 5):

It's using the GECOS field from your line in the `passwd` file (courtesy of `getpwuid`). You can change the author name that shows up by setting the `AUTHOR` environment variable, although this doesn't seem documented. As for overriding the entire thing: not so much, unless you want to write your own `catalyst.pl` that uses a custom subclass of `Catalyst::Helper`, or submit the patch to -Runtime to let everyone do that.:)